# How to get a value from hidden inside tables selected row

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="listWrapper">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="list" class="ig_DarkBlue7Item iggWG_DarkBlue7Item tableLineHeight">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="listHeader" class="igg_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption iggWG_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption" colkey="UstKriterDegeri">
                <span role="button" class="filtreButtonUKD"><img src="Icon/filtre.gif"></span>ÜST KRİTER DEĞERİ
            </td>
            <td id="listHeader" class="igg_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption iggWG_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption" colkey="Isim">
                <span role="button" class="filtreButtonI"><img src="Icon/filtre.gif"></span>İSİM
            </td>
            <td id="listHeader" class="igg_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption iggWG_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption" colkey="KolayKod">
                <span role="button" class="filtreButtonKK"><img src="Icon/filtre.gif"></span>KOLAY KOD
            </td>
            <td id="listHeader" class="igg_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption iggWG_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption" colkey="AsilDeğer">
                <span role="button" class="filtreButtonAD"><img src="Icon/filtre.gif"></span>ASIL DEĞER
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item iggWG_DarkBlue7ActiveRow"><td><span class="ig_DarkBlue7Item">20</span><input type="hidden" name="LNGSAKLAMABASLIK" value="1"></td><td>Kat4</td><td>10</td><td>522</td></tr>
        <tr class="item iggWG_DarkBlue7RowOdd"><td><span class="ig_DarkBlue7Item">21</span><input type="hidden" name="LNGSAKLAMABASLIK" value="2"></td><td>Kat5</td><td>11</td><td>523</td></tr>
        <tr class="item"><td><span class="ig_DarkBlue7Item">22</span><input type="hidden" name="LNGSAKLAMABASLIK" value="3"></td><td>Kat4</td><td>152</td><td>546</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

iggWG_DarkBlue7ActiveRow class is my selected row.
I want to get value from hidden in the selected row.
What is the jquery code for this.

```
var secilenId = $('tr.iggWG_DarkBlue7ActiveRow td input:hidden[name="LNGSAKLAMABASLIK"]').val();
```

I have tried this but its not working.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? I just tried it in a JSFiddle and your code worked fine. I got the value "1".

Comment: Your code works, as you can see in my answer's snippet.

Comment: You want the value in input or are you calling value to the item price ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I want the value in input

Comment: @Raptord "undefined" in the console :(

Comment: @Yiğit, conexxo has already proved that your code is correct. Probably you have something different from what you posted here in your code. Double check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was my row select code :

```
$('tr').on('click', function () {
    $('tr').removeClass('iggWG_DarkBlue7ActiveRow');
    if ($(this).hasClass('item')) {
        $(this).addClass('iggWG_DarkBlue7ActiveRow');
    }
});
```

and my trigger button was inside another table 
when I click for get hidden value, selected rows class was going
then I convert this code to this :

```
$('tr.item').on('click', function () {
    $('tr').removeClass('iggWG_DarkBlue7ActiveRow');
    if ($(this).hasClass('item')) {
        $(this).addClass('iggWG_DarkBlue7ActiveRow');
    }
});
```

added "item" class to my onclick selector

Answer (score 0):

Both jQuery and native JS DOM selection works:

```js
console.log("native js logs " + document.querySelector('.iggWG_DarkBlue7ActiveRow input[type=hidden][name=LNGSAKLAMABASLIK]').value)

console.log("jquery logs " + $('tr.iggWG_DarkBlue7ActiveRow td input:hidden[name="LNGSAKLAMABASLIK"]').val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="list" class="ig_DarkBlue7Item iggWG_DarkBlue7Item tableLineHeight">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="listHeader" class="igg_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption iggWG_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption" colkey="UstKriterDegeri">
                <span role="button" class="filtreButtonUKD"><img src="Icon/filtre.gif"></span>ÜST KRİTER DEĞERİ
            </td>
            <td id="listHeader" class="igg_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption iggWG_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption" colkey="Isim">
                <span role="button" class="filtreButtonI"><img src="Icon/filtre.gif"></span>İSİM
            </td>
            <td id="listHeader" class="igg_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption iggWG_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption" colkey="KolayKod">
                <span role="button" class="filtreButtonKK"><img src="Icon/filtre.gif"></span>KOLAY KOD
            </td>
            <td id="listHeader" class="igg_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption iggWG_DarkBlue7HeaderCaption" colkey="AsilDeğer">
                <span role="button" class="filtreButtonAD"><img src="Icon/filtre.gif"></span>ASIL DEĞER
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item iggWG_DarkBlue7ActiveRow"><td><span class="ig_DarkBlue7Item">20</span><input type="hidden" name="LNGSAKLAMABASLIK" value="1"></td><td>Kat4</td><td>10</td><td>522</td></tr>
        <tr class="item iggWG_DarkBlue7RowOdd"><td><span class="ig_DarkBlue7Item">21</span><input type="hidden" name="LNGSAKLAMABASLIK" value="2"></td><td>Kat5</td><td>11</td><td>523</td></tr>
        <tr class="item"><td><span class="ig_DarkBlue7Item">22</span><input type="hidden" name="LNGSAKLAMABASLIK" value="3"></td><td>Kat4</td><td>152</td><td>546</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can try

```
var secilenId = $('tr.iggWG_DarkBlue7ActiveRow td  input:hidden[name="LNGSAKLAMABASLIK"]').getAttribute('value')
```

Comment: What  if the `value` *property* has changed (this won't affect the `value` attribute!)?